# How to make a mute command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[My code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dqok.jpg)

How do I make a mute command?

Comment: Have a look at the discord.py docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to get more info. Stack Overflow isn't a place for other's to write you code. I will tell you however, for a mute command you need to save the user's current roles, remove those roles and then assign a muted role. You must then time how long they are muted for and remove the muted role after this time, then assign the initial roles. If you need any help with any parts of this after making an attempt, please ask a more specific question, as opposed to asking for the whole thing to be done for you.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
@bot.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def mute(ctx,*,member : discord.Member):
  muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role([the mute role id])
  await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
  await ctx.send(f'**{member}** has been unmuted!')
```

Reply if it works